# C++ How to return dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I'm getting no matching function for call to error how can I fix this without using vectors.

This is my header, I'm getting the error at `fList` method part in `cpp`.

```
    class Flight{
    public:
    Flight(int fly,int rw,int st);
    ~Flight();
    Flight* fList(int& sizeOfArray);




    private:
    int FlightNumber;
    int row;
    int seat;
    int* flightArray;


};
```

This is my `cpp`:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;
        #include "Flight.h"

        Flight::Flight(int fly,int rw,int st){
            FlightNumber = fly;
            row = rw;
            seat = st;

        }
        Flight::~Flight(){};
        Flight* Flight::fList(int& sizeOfArray){
            flightArray = new Flight[sizeOfArray];
            return flightArray;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with using an `std::vector`? Seems like it would solve your problem perfectly.

Comment: Where is `flightArray` vaariable defined? It is usually helpful to post the errors you want to fix.

Comment: This code is for my homework so using vectors are forbidden is there anyone can help me solving this error?

Comment: `private:
    int FlightNumber;
    int row;
    int seat;
    int* flightArray;
`

Comment: Flight array is a private property in my header

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would help if you actually said what the error is.

Comment: Why is `sizeOfArray` declared as reference?

Comment: You should add a default constructor of `Flight` as it is requested.

Comment: @MikeCAT not sure if this is enough. The overall design is wrong IMO.

Comment: You have to allocate memory in the constructor for the flightArray and then deallocate memory in the destructor like this: delete[]flightArray; and in your fList you have to use new int

Comment: Have you read the error message? What does it say?

Comment: You should tell us what the homework assignment is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

```
int* flightArray;
```

should be

```
Flight* flightArray;
```

Your code is allocating an array of `Flights` but your variable is declared for integers not Flights.

Plus as pointed out by @MikeCAT you need to default constructor for `Flight` if you are going to allocate them with `new[]`.

Comment: im still getting the same error, no matching function for call to Flight::Flight()

Comment: @saitcanbaskol Well that's the other problem that MikeCAT spotted. You really should **post the error message**.

Comment: I think there are fundamental design problems in this code. IMO they cannot be resolved just by changing some details here and there. In his design a flight contains a list of flights which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question, i ll format my question with error code in 10mins thanks for your all attention.

Comment: @saitcanbaskol When you use `new[]` your objects are constructed with the default constructor. Your class doesn't have a default constructor and so you get errors. I hate to labour the point, but `std::vector` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @saitcanbaskol Error message should be posted as text, not image. Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)